Iframe is not accessible for selecting (nodriver)
Using nodriver for seatgeek.com, handling initial captcha. I need to press audio button,
but when trying to find this element, it raises AttributeError. Happens in the code that tries to address the frame content, which is uninitialised for some reason:
  File "/home/pooh/work/xxx/./seatgeek.py", line 324, in get_result_nd
    res=await self.page.select_all('#captcha__audio__button', include_frames=True) # , best_match=True
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pooh/venv12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/tab.py", line 307, in select_all
    items.extend(await fr.query_selector_all(selector))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pooh/venv12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/element.py", line 797, in query_selector_all
    return await self.tab.query_selector_all(selector, _node=self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pooh/venv12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nodriver/core/tab.py", line 377, in query_selector_all
    cdp.dom.query_selector_all(doc.node_id, selector)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node_id'

In tab.select_all it understands there's a frame, but the latter seems to be without actual content. Can it be stale? The element has no children nor content. I've tried to await fr there, but no luck.
